# SWift 3.0 delegate for navigation bar button

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I was trying to use this SuperTViewController.swift as a base view controller and set delegate for back button. ProjectTableViewController.swift is one of the viewcontrollers applying the delegates . ProjectTableViewController.swift indeed has the button due to extended class. But I want custom back() for different actions for each different page. When it comes to execution
,  print("project") cannot be run. WOuld you please tell me the details for implementing the delegate and apply ? The following is my code ,.

SuperTViewController.swift

```
protocol backProtocol : UINavigationBarDelegate {
      func back ()
}


class SuperTViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: backProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "btn_add")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ButtonTapped))


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

    func ButtonTapped() {
        print("Button Tapped")
        delegate?.back()

    }

}
```

ProjectTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ProjectTableViewController: SuperTViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate?.back()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

    func back () {
        print("project")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, extend (implement) the protocol.Then,  assign delegate to self

```
class ProjectTableViewController: SuperTViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self

    }

    ....
}
```